# Print Intent for Google Cloud Print App

Tags: android, google-cloud-print

As of today, the official Cloud Print documentation from Google still tells you to include the PrintDialogActivity into your app to print documents using Google Cloud Print. However, it's now also possible to print using the official Google Cloud Print app. I couldn't find any documentation for that though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is pretty straightforward, but it still took me a few days to figure it out:

```
Intent printIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
printIntent.setType("text/html");
printIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TITLE, "some cool title for your document");
printIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);

startActivity(printIntent);
```

That's the correct way to do it. **Important:** `Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE` does NOT work at the moment.