# Print reports from Android device using Delphi

Tags: android, delphi, firemonkey

I am developing an app using Delphi XE8 and I need to print a report.

The report has more pages so I can't create a simple image and share it.

The idea is to use the FMX.Printer.

But the TPrintDialog works only on Windows not on Android. 
How can I select a printer from the Cloud Print list?

Do you have any suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If the official [Google Cloud Print](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.cloudprint&hl=en) app is installed on the device, then you should be able to access it with an Intent as described in the answer to this question: [Print Intent for Google Cloud Print App](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17383588/80901)

```
Intent printIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
printIntent.setType("text/html");
printIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TITLE, "some cool title for your document");
printIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);

startActivity(printIntent);
```

I guess that Android then will show a dialog with the available options, including the Cloud Print printers.

Google Cloud Print documentation: https://developers.google.com/cloud-print/docs/android

API to retrieve the printer list: https://developers.google.com/cloud-print/docs/proxyinterfaces#list

Comment: Thanks good start point. But how can implement/use the intent in Delphi source?

Comment: I would be interested in this too. Printing is something that we need to do with Delphi (D10 here).

Answer (score 0):

Putting this into Delphi should look something like:

```
uses
...
  FMX.Platform.Android,
  Androidapi.Helpers,
  Androidapi.JNI.GraphicsContentViewText,
  Androidapi.JNI.Embarcadero,
...

var
  printIntent: JIntent;
begin
  printIntent := TJIntent.Create;
  printIntent.setAction(TJIntent.JavaClass.ACTION_SEND);
  printIntent.setType(StringToJString('text/html'));
  printIntent.putExtra(TJIntent.JavaClass.EXTRA_TITLE, StringToJString('Testing print from Android'));
  printIntent.putExtra(TJIntent.JavaClass.EXTRA_STREAM, StringToJString(uri));
  if MainActivity.getPackageManager.queryIntentActivities(printIntent, TJPackageManager.JavaClass.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY).size > 0 then //Checks if there is at least one application capable of receiving the intent.
    MainActivity.startActivity(printIntent) //Calls startActivity() to send the intent to the system.
  else
    ShowMessage('Receiver not found');
```

Based on the sample code from http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/CodeExamples/Seattle/en/FMX.Android_Intents_Sample